# Python: Reset index of Pandas.Series with datetime

Tags: python, indexing, statsmodels

I´m trying to use the "seasonal_decompose" method from the statsmodels library:

```
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_load_log)
```

When trying to execude the line the following error occurs:

'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'

That is because my ts_load_log looks like the following:

[image: ts_load_log]

Now I´m trying to convert my index! Therefore I have created the following data frame which contains the dates for the values in the ts_load_log:

```
df_datetimes  = pd.to_datetime(df_load_per_hour['Market Day']) + pd.to_timedelta(df_load_per_hour['HourEnding'] - 1, unit='h')
```

That looks like:

[image: df_datetimes]

Is there a way to reset the index of the ts_load_log Series with the help of the data frame df_datetimes so that the decomposition works? Or is there an easier way instead of creating a new data frame? Or am I totaly wrong ?

I already tried:

```
test = ts_load_log.to_frame()
test2 = df_datetimes.to_frame()
test = test.reindex(test2[0])
```

But I think that is unnecessary. Additionaly it does not work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the datetimeIndex method of pandas it should work:

```
test = ts_load_log.to_frame()
test2 = df_datetimes.to_frame()
test.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(test2[0])
```

After that just convert the data frame object into a Series object like:

```
test = pd.Series(test)
```